# Why WM_LBUTTONUP message dispear in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, message

The `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` will run when I write like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    Label1.Caption:='ddddddd';
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    ShowMessage('mouseup');
end;
```

But when I write like this, the WM_LBUTTONUP dispear and Edit1MouseUp will not run, why?

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    ShowMessage('mousedown');
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    ShowMessage('mouseup');
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second scenario, the edit control is never posted a `WM_LBUTTONUP`, hence `OnMouseUp` event is not fired.

When you call `ShowMessage` in `OnMouseDown`, a dialog is launched. This not only releases the mouse capture from the edit control, it also disables the form. With both, the message has nowhere to be posted: not to a window with the capture, and not to a window under the cursor (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

You can simulate the behavior with this code, without showing a message:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Assert(GetCapture = Edit1.Handle);
  ReleaseCapture;
  Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('mouseup'); // will not fire.
end;
```

The moral is: do not use `ShowMessage` to debug situations involving activation/focus. As it may not be quite evident as in this case, in general do not use it as a debugging tool at all.

Comment: The message may be placed in the queue if the mouse is released before the thread has processed the mouse down

Comment: @David - The thread processes mouse down first, this processing causes the mouse up message not to be posted.

Comment: The thread processes the message when it gets round to pumping its queue. Whether or not the mouse has been released by that point is indeterminate.

Comment: @David - Maybe so if the application is busy executing code while the edit is clicked. However, the answer answers the question, the message is *not posted* when you click in the edit when the application is idle.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a big fuss about this. Just to stress the async nature of input messages.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `ShowMessage`, that shows a modal window. The call to `ShowMessage` does not return until the modal window closes. The modal window runs its own message loop, and that eats the mouse up message. So, the `WM_LBUTTONUP` that is in the message queue already, or is about to be placed in the message queue, is actually processed by the message box rather than your Delphi form.

How exactly is that message processed? Well, it depends. If the message was posted before the modal window is shown, then it will be dispatched to the owner window, which is disabled. If it is posted after the modal window is shown, then it may be dispatched to the modal window.

This is one of the reasons why actions are invoked by mouse up rather than mouse down. Perhaps you've not noticed that yet, but try clicking on a button in any common application and note that the response only occurs when the mouse goes up. Indeed if you press the mouse down on a button, move the cursor away from the button, and then release the button, the action does not trigger.

Now try something similar with your second code sample. Press the mouse down in the edit control but don't release it immediately. Note that the result of the mouse going down is that a modal window is now showing. It runs its own message loop and your form is disabled. Now release the mouse button. Clearly the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message is going to be pulled off the queue by the modal window's message loop.

Comment: Your answer is also interesting. But I think the most important reason is that the form is disabled, not the modal eats the mouse up message. Because even it has own message loop, this message should be sent(dispatchMessage) to the owner by its handle, doesn't it? But the disable form will not receive or ignore the message automatically?

Comment: It's more complicated than that. If the dialog shows under the cusror, and then you release the mouse, where does the message go then? There are multiple scenarios to consider: message posted before dialog shown, message posted after dialog shown are two obvious ones.

Comment: @user - Yes, a disabled window is what it is, it doesn't receive mouse/keyboard input. - David - in the scenario in the question mouse up message cannot be posted before the dialog is shown because the dialog is shown in the mouse down event.

Comment: to  Sertac Akyuz, I understand finally. Each disable the form, or create a new message loop who eat the message, will work. look at this: procedure TForm1.Edit1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Assert(GetCapture = Edit1.Handle);
  ReleaseCapture;
  Form2.Show;
end;

Comment: @stlcours - That doesn't eat anything when I test, mouse up is fired.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That's not so. Input messages are asynchronous. There's no reason to believe that the application will have pulled off the button down before the button up is placed on the queue.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, not just show, you add ReleaseCapture to test:begin
  Assert(GetCapture = Edit1.Handle);
  ReleaseCapture;
  Form2.Show;
end;

Comment: @stlcours - Yes, that's what I tested.